# How to add miliseconds to my timer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, countdown

I try to put milliseconds to my timer, but they act like seconds instead of milliseconds. They're already after the seconds. But there not acting like the milliseconds. Also I have been trying to make the percentage see how far the countdown is. So how can I fix this?

This is the link with the whole script: http://embed.plnkr.co/hUeAAzBBszAnCq7FdeGO/

```js
// Code goes here
window.addEventListener('load', start);

function start() {
  countdown();
}

function isNumberKey(evt) {
  var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
  if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
  //if charcode is keycode more then 31 and keycode less then 48 and more then 57 return false 
  {
    return false;
    //aren't numbers
  } else {
    return true;
    //only can type numbers
  }
}

function countdown(val) {
  var counter = parseInt(val);
  var myVar = setInterval(function() {
    if (counter >= 0) {
      document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = Math.floor(counter / 60) + ":" + ("0" + Math.floor(counter) % 60).slice(-2) + "." + Math.floor((counter % 1000) * 1000) / 1000;
      //counter/60 calculates the minute and counter%60 calculates the seconds.
      counter--;
    }
    if (counter < 0) {
      document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = "That was the countdown";
    }
  }, 1000)
}

var stop = 0;

function decrease() {
  var percent = Number($('#counter span').text());
  if (percent > stop) {
    $('#counter span').text(--percent);
    var t = setTimeout(decrease, 1000);
  }
}

setTimeout(decrease, 1000);

function count() {
  var input = document.getElementById("number_input").value;
  countdown(input);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

only numbers please :
<input type="text" placeholder="type in a number" id="number_input" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" />
<button onclick="count()">tel af</button>

<p id="timer">0</p>
<div id="counter">
  <p><span>100</span>%</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Your `setInterval` interval is 1000 milliseconds.

Comment: If I customizable the 1000 to 100 the secondes are going to fast

Comment: you have to change the code

Answer (score 0):

your timeout is setup wrongly, it been setup for every 1 sec which is causing the problem.

1000 = 1 sec
100 = 100 milli sec... now adjust it as per your need

The way you are managing counter needs to be isolated or change the HTML change logic differntly

Answer (score 0):

You are using 1000 in your Timeout and Interval.  That number is in Milliseconds. You will have to do some math to count down seconds and milliseconds at the same time.

Not related to your question: You are using JQuery and getElementById. Why not change

```
document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML
```

into

```
$("#timer").html(...)
```